# Applying for tourist visa to Australia with juvenile record and speeding tickets

Tags: paperwork, australia, tourist-visas, applications, criminal-records

I am attempting to apply for a tourist visa to Australia. When I get to the question about prior convictions, it says any past convictions, not substantial like some other countries do, and I have a juvenile offense from when I was 15. I did not spend 12 months in juvie, just two weeks and a 12 month probation period. I was told it would not show after I was 18, but this is leading me to believe I should check yes and not no. I also have a speeding ticket that I am wondering if I should list on the application or wait until the IPC to say yes to. I am over 18 now and live in the United States.

Comment: Are you over 18 now?

Comment: For completeness, what is your citizenship (and country of residence, if different).

Comment: A speeding ticket (in most places) is a moving violation, not a criminal conviction.

Comment: If I were you I’d consider getting a police report to submit with your application. Does this answer your question? [Australia ETA with prior speeding ticket](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/126763/australia-eta-with-prior-speeding-ticket)

Comment: Yes I am over 18 now. I live in the United States.

Comment: Speeding tickets will not be considered, unless it involves criminal charges. The application simply wants to know of any criminal charges you have been given, regardless of age. My advice is to be as honest as possible and it won't be any trouble for you. They're mostly concerned about drug smugglers or illegal labor. They are not so concerned about what you did as a teenager. As long as you are a genuine tourist you should have no trouble getting the tourist visa.

Answer (score 3):

On the basis of your brief description, you should include your youth conviction. If you tell the truth, you won't be denied a tourist visa. You may have to fill out more forms.

"Traffic Tickets" are typically not convictions.  If you have been called to court, and been convicted, you should list the convictions. They won't matter (you've already said there was no jail time), but convictions must be listed.

You should also list things that you think might count as a conviction somewhere else, even if you only got a ticket: for traffic offenses, that's anything involving drugs, drink driving, or personal injury.

As it happens, simple ordinary speeding offenses mostly don't give rise to convictions in the USA, and mostly don't give rise to convictions in Canada or Australia, so they aren't 'virtual convictions' that you have to list along with 'technical convictions'.